# How to customise the string value in uiweb view ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

In my application I want to show the URL link value as "Click here to see the link" in UIWebView?

```
  For ex: link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pii4G8FkCA4

  I want to show it as in UIWebView as "click here to see the link"
```

Can any one please help me to how to do that?

Comment: Are you loading a html template in the uiwebview? If it is refer this http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    NSString *html = @"<a href=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pii4G8FkCA4/\">click here to see the link</a>";
    [webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

This will help you to load URL in webView.

Answer (score 1):

try like this ,you will get,

```
UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
  webview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
  NSString *html = @"<a href=\"www.youtube.com/watch?v=pii4G8FkCA4\">click here to see the link</a>";
  [webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
  [self.view addSubview:webview];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TRy this,
 viewcontroller.h

```
 IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

viewController.m

```
    NSString *strHtml = @"<a href=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pii4G8FkCA4/\">click here to see the link</a>";
[webview loadHTMLString:strHtml baseURL:nil];
```